# PHP regular expressions - using metacharacters as delimiters

Tags: php, regex

So I've been reading the php (PCRE) regular expression doco, and I've noted the section about delimiters (http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) says:

"A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character."

It also talks about using brackets as delimiters:

"Bracket style delimiters do not need to be escaped when they are used as meta characters within the pattern, but as with other delimiters they must be escaped when they are used as literal characters."

My question is, what about using other regex meta characters as delimiters, as well as using them as meta characters within the pattern?

From the testing I've done it's not possible to use a meta character such as '|' as both a delimiter and a meta character in the pattern. I can't think of any reason why one would need to do this, but I'm curious as to what the 'right' answer is.

Comment: I'm actually surprised to learn that PHP accepts (in their example) `+` as a delimiter, when that is also a metacharacter in regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, choosing a delimiter character that can have special meaning within the pattern could cause headaches that should be easily avoided. So don't do it, of course.

But to fulfill your curiosity, it appears your observations are correct that you cannot retain a character's special meaning if you use it as a delimiter. Let's browse through the relevant [PHP source for PCRE functions](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c) to see why. (Some code omitted here for simplicity.)

First, it skips over any leading whitespace it encounters.

```
while (isspace((int)*(unsigned char *)p)) p++;
```

After that, the `delimiter` is selected as the first character in the string.

```
delimiter = *p++;
```

Next, it is determined whether the `end_delimiter` is going to be the same character as the `start_delimiter` or if it will be the complement to an opening bracket character (i.e., `)` complements `(`, `]` complements `[`, etc.). Recall how the manual explicitly states that bracket-style characters are treated specially in this way.

```
start_delimiter = delimiter;
if ((pp = strchr("([{< )]}> )]}>", delimiter)))
    delimiter = pp[5];
end_delimiter = delimiter;

pp = p;
```

If the delimiters are not complementary brackets – rather, both characters are identical – the ending delimiter is determined to be the first matching character that is not escaped.

```
while (*pp != 0) {
    if (*pp == '\\' && pp[1] != 0) pp++;
    else if (*pp == delimiter)
        break;
    pp++;
}
```

All pretty straightforward, but once the delimiters are found, the contained `pattern` is determined as the verbatim string between the two delimiter characters.

```
pattern = estrndup(p, pp-p);
```

Therefore, any characters you escaped within your pattern originally will still be transferred as escaped characters to the pattern parser itself in the underlying PCRE functions.

```
re = pcre_compile(pattern, ...
```

At this point, the isolated pattern will be the same no matter which delimiters you had selected. The actual regex engine is completely oblivious to your choice.

I hope that's what you were asking. :-)